# How to send ga(...) events with Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm changing google analytics for google tag manager on an existing website. This website also uses google e-commerce, so I have a few custom `ga()` calls related to the e-commerce being done on some pages.

The problem is that because the google analytics script loads asynchronously, `ga()` is not defined anymore when I'm trying to send some e-commerce related data.
I've found a workaround somewhere:

```
window['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = 'ga';
window['ga'] = window['ga'] || function() {
  (window['ga'].q = window['ga'].q || []).push(arguments)
};
```

But, although I've not the "ga is not defined" problem anymore, it still doesn't work.

I don't see anything on the google dashboard. I also don't see anything on the debugging messages (in the developer console).

What seems to be happening is that the GA script loaded with GMT is not using these variables I've set but I'm not sure how to fix it or if it is even possible to keep using my `ga()` calls with GMT.

I know that I can do it with `dataLayer` but I'm trying to avoid to rewrite a bunch of working code just for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen an implementation that does it like this:

```
  window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
  ga('create', UA-XXXXXXXXXX, 'auto');
  ga('require', 'ecommerce');
```

maybe that works out for you as well.

if you use enhanced e-commerce then the code below the "ga('create..." hast to change from:

```
ga('require', 'ecommerce');
```

to:

```
ga('require', 'ec');
```

The order is important here, events can be send **after** those functions.