# ga() function Google Analytics implemented as a tag in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I need to use the custom `ga('send')` function to send data that's triggered on a form submit, specifically through Marketo.

On web properties where GA is installed as a script tag, this works great. However, on one site I need to do this on, GA is installed as a tag through GTM. It's apparently a best practice.

Basically the code looks like this (for context):

```
form.onSuccess(function (values, url) {
    console.log('success');
    ...
    ga('send', 'event', {
       eventCategory: 'form',
       eventAction: 'submit',
       eventLabel: 'Form Submit'
     });
     ...
     return false;
 });
```

I did some research

[How to send ga(...) events with Google Tag Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50487788/how-to-send-ga-events-with-google-tag-manager)

[Google Analytics Code Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716542/google-analytics-code-explanation)

The premise is that I need to define the `ga()` function in the first place - so I do that like so:

```
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', "UA-XXXXXXXX", 'auto');
form.onSuccess(function (values, url) {
     console.log('success');
     ...
     ga('send', 'event', {
           eventCategory: 'form',
           eventAction: 'submit',
           eventLabel: 'Form Submit'
     });
     ...
     return false;
 });
```

I can see the `console.log("success") and no errors are being thrown but I'm not seeing the form submission event being logged in GA.

Any ideas? How do I do custom events with a Google Tag Manager implementation of GA vs a script tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to track custom events when Google Analytics is managed by Google Tag Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55675935/how-to-track-custom-events-when-google-analytics-is-managed-by-google-tag-manage)

Answer (score 2):

On marketo form pages where GA is implemented through a GTM tag, then you should look into using [custom datalayer events](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#events) for this.

Don't be afraid of the word "custom", essentially instead of the ga() function, you would do:

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'event_name'});
```

So your code becomes:

```
form.onSuccess(function (values, url) {console.log('success');
...dataLayer.push({'event': 'form-submit'});...return false;});
```

**THEN IN GTM:**

1. Create a trigger based on that custom event ('form-submit') you just coded to push to the datalayer, like so:
   [image]
2. Then create a GA tag, set track type "EVENT", fill in the category, action and label as you wish. Then attach the trigger you created in step 1. Like so:
   [image]
3. Preview or submit everything to see it working.

Comment: Great answer! I pushed the update on the tag and the JS code, is there usually a delay when we'll see it in the analytics panel?

Comment: Yes there is usually a delay, but if you go to "Real Time > Events" in GA, you should see it as you click on the forms. Make sure if you have tracking/ad blockers, you turn them off.

You can also use GTM Debug mode to confirm that the tag is firing on submit.